# iecapt utility - i am trying to get a screenshot of a site that is password protected using IECAPT, how do i pass in the creds?

Tags: internet-explorer, command-line, batch-file, iecapt

I am trying to get a screenshot of a site that is password protected using IECAPT, any ideas on how I could pass in the creds?

Comment: I think you cannot do it. You can only access the login page.

Answer (score 1):

IEcapt basically calls a fresh instance of Internet Explorer using the ATL Windows library. The only way to adapt IECapt to use login credentials would be to convert it into a Windows GUI app that allows you to login to the site before fetching urls requiring a login session.

Unfortunately, it's no longer being maintaned, and only provided as a console app.